# How to splice an array based on the length i pass and also re-initialize array with remaining elements

Tags: javascript

> This is the array

```
pickelement        = ["2123","149","3096","1471"];
var shiftlength    = 4; //this is also dynamic
```

> From the above i need to splice in loop, length to splice will be dynamic

```
for(var s = 0;s<shiftlength;s++){

nofofillres = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=Resources'+s+']'[shiftreslength].value.length;

searchInput = pickelement .splice(nofofillres); // this is not working as expected
console.log(searchInput); // Each time same number of elements is coming

// I need an answer suppose if
nofofillres for 1st iteration is 1 and second is 1 and third is 1 and fourth is 1 Then
spliced element should be "2123"
spliced element should be "149"
spliced element should be "3096"
spliced element should be "1471"
and also each time when  sliced pickelement should be reinitalzied  as below
 ["149","3096","1471"]
 ["3096","1471"];
["1471"];
Please provide an answer m stuck with it

}
```

Comment: can you pleasse provide your expected result?

Comment: Hi, My expected output should be in one variable it should get spliced element and remaining elements should be reinitialized and perform same in loop

Comment: could you write the output that you want. Or simply take an example and show the result that you want.

Comment: You also need to reformat your question, enter a new line before your code so that it displays in the question. Have a look at the preview before posting.

Comment: You need to provide at least two arguments to `.splice()`, the index at which to delete, and the number of elements to delete. What do you mean "re-initialise array with remaining elements"? If you use `.splice()` to remove an element then the array now contains the "remaining" elements so what further initialisation is necessary?

Comment: each time remaining elements is displaying same as ["149","3096","1471"]    in each iteration. Am suppose to get if(s == 0){
                        
                         ResMapped = ResSelectedInitial.splice(nofofillres);
       resString =                 ResSelectedInitial.join(",");
                          } // for first iteration it is fine working But from second means when s= 1 and so on i need to splice with new array as["149","3096","1471"] and s= 2 ["3096",1471] and so on

Comment: Your code as shown contains syntax errors, e.g., missing `)` in the call to `Ext.ComponentQuery.query(` - speaking of which, **is `.query()` asynchronous?** Perhaps you should `console.log(nofofillres)` before doing the `.splice()`, to make sure it is the index you expect. And note my previous point about `.splice()` taking multiple arguments...

Comment: nofofillres is displaying correctly , ie  for me to pick theelement from  length given as nofofillres , from an array when i pick length two it wil remove two from array next time it is not working as array is still same

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is what you are looking for. I've edited the original code based on your comment

```
    var pickelement = ["2123","149","3096","1471"];
    var shiftlength = 4;
    for(var s = 0;s<shiftlength;s++){
      var nofofillres = 1;
      var splicedArray = pickelement.splice(0,nofofillres);
      console.log("Spliced Array of Iteration : " + (s+1) + " is ");
      console.log(splicedArray);
      console.log("pickelement after Iteration : " + (s+1) + " is ");
      console.log(pickelement);
    }
```

Output

```
    Spliced Array of Iteration : 1 is 
    ["2123"]
    pickelement after Iteration : 1 is 
    ["149", "3096", "1471"]
    Spliced Array of Iteration : 2 is 
    ["149"]
    pickelement after Iteration : 2 is 
    ["3096", "1471"]
    Spliced Array of Iteration : 3 is 
    ["3096"]
    pickelement after Iteration : 3 is 
    ["1471"]
    Spliced Array of Iteration : 4 is 
    ["1471"]
    pickelement after Iteration : 4 is 
    []
```

Comment: Hi, Sorry am not looking for the any even numbers , I am looking for ResString = [ 2123,140 ] //if nofres is 2 i.e length to pick the elements next iteration if noof res is 1 then ResString = [ 3096 ]

Comment: Please see if the edited code is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi  Jaganathan Nanthakumar, This is what am looking for ,will try this  and post if working fine . Thank you